# Why isn't addEventListener working for this project?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("onclick", mouseover);

function mouseover() {
  this.style.color = " yellow ";
  this.style.backgroundcolor = "green";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value= "Submit" id="btn" />
```

Comment: `background.color` should be `.backgroundColor`. Aside from that, who knows. You didn't give a full example.

Comment: Look at the developer console in your browser.

Comment: It's `addEventListener("click", mouseover);`

Comment: in brackets its the words its automatically typing in is onclick

Comment: Heres the full code:                                                                <html>
<head> <title> EventListener </title> </head>
<body>
                <input type="button" value= "Submit" id="btn" />
    </body>
<script>
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("onclick", mouseover);
    
            function mouseover()
    {
            this.style.color = " yellow ";
        this.style.backgroundcolor = "green";
        
    }
    </script>
</html>

Comment: Edit your question to add more info. While doing so, take a moment to learn how to properly highlight the code you post. You can click the question mark to the right of the buttons above the text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attach a listener to an event named *click*, you need to do either of the following:

```js
object.onclick = function(event) { ... }
object.addEventListener('click', function(event) { ... });
```

**There's no "on" before the event name in the second approach**, so in your case, your code should be:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener("click", mouseover);
                   // ^-- note no "on" here

function mouseover() {
  this.style.color = "yellow";
  this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value= "Submit" id="btn" />
```

(Also note that it's `backgroundColor`, not `background.color`, and there should be no spaces within the color strings.)

Comment: Great explanation. Please remember, that `background.color`is still wrong, it has to be `backgroundColor.

Comment: @JHolub Thanks for the correction, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues, the comments explain what was wrong.

```js
//define the function first (best practice)
function mouseovera() { 
  this.style.color = "yellow";  //remove the spaces
  this.style.backgroundColor = "green"; //It is camel case not dot
}

var btn = document.getElementById("a");
btn.addEventListener("click", mouseovera);  //it is click, not onclick
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">a</button>
```

Now a better way to do this would be with classes. Using classList, you can easily toggle the class or add the class when the button is clicked. And when you use a class, it is easy to maintain they styles outside of the JavaScript code.

```js
function makeActive() { 
  this.classList.toggle("active")
}

var btn = document.getElementById("a");
btn.addEventListener("click", makeActive);
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.active {
   color: yellow;
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">a</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just `click` instead of `onclick`.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", mouseover);

function mouseover() {
  this.style.color = " yellow ";
  this.style.backgroundColor = "green";        
}
```

Also the above comment was correct that to reference background-color from Javascript use `style.backgroundColor`